# PyTorch VERY different results on different machines using docker and CPU

Tags: python, docker, testing, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to create some CI tests for a deep learning model and therefore created a Dockerfile to install PyTorch and all my requirements and finally run the tests.

```
FROM pytorch/pytorch
ADD . / project/
RUN (cd project/; pip install -r requirements.txt)
CMD ( cd project/; pytest -v --cov=my_project)
```

The tests are basically computing an image from 0 - 1  and comparing it to a reference image (saved as npy). The test is checking
if the avg L2 norm of the pixels is below a threshold of `1e-7`.

```py
diff_image = np.linalg.norm(target_image_np - reference_image_np, axis=2)
avg_error = np.mean(diff_image)
assert avg_error < 1e-7
```

The tests pass 12/15 test cases. However, 3 cases are failing quite badly.

```
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_nst.py::test_nst_gatys - assert 0.0021541715 < 1e-07       
FAILED test_nst.py::test_nst_gatys_style - assert 0.12900369 < 1e-07
FAILED test_nst.py::test_nst_wct - assert 0.027357593 < 1e-07
=================== 3 failed, 12 passed in 670.27s (0:11:10) ===================
```

The weird thing is that this ONLY happens on the CI server. On my local machine, all tests pass. Does anybody have an idea why this is happening? As far as I know, using the CPU as well as fixed seeds should return at least results which differ only numerically.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution myself. It is required to set the number of threads to one. Finally, this is all the code required to get reproducible results on different machines.

```py
    np.random.seed(42)
    torch.manual_seed(42)
    os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = "42"
    torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
    torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
    torch.set_num_threads(1)
```

Comment: I've been bonking my head over this problem for like 5 hours now. If  this is  the solution im gonna kiss you

Comment: I spend more than 1 day to think about why the difference... Until I saw this post. Really thankful...